# Why are my numbers displayed with a comma?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, decimal

i am using symfony 2.8, i am displaying a form with decimal numbers, in my html, i have had dump (form.numberwithdecial) and this have a format (66.45) for example, but when my form is rendered, it has this format (66,45).
I have calculates with these numbers, and its a problem., because my resutl return NaN. How can I render my numbers with decimal with point and not comma? Thank you.

```
Twig:
... some code
<td class="form-group tdpvd">
            {% if form_errors(articulo.pvd) %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.pvd, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control pvd error listener', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% else %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.pvd, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control pvd listener', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="form-group tdpvp">{{ dump(articulo) }}
            {% if form_errors(articulo.pvp) %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.pvp, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control pvp pvp__articulos__ error listener', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% else %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.pvp, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control pvp pvp__articulos__ listener', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="form-group tdcantidad" style="width: 10em">
            {% if form_errors(articulo.cantidad) %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.cantidad, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control cantidad__articulos__ error listener cantidad', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% else %}
                {{ form_widget(articulo.cantidad, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control cantidad__articulos__ listener cantidad', 'data-prototype':'__articulos__'}}) }}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
... some code
```

EDIT:

I have changed my config.yml for my twig configuration:

```
app/config/config.yml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    number_format:
        decimals: 2
        decimal_point: '.'
```

Comment: Check your globalization settings. The comma is the decimal separator in some locations.

Comment: How can i show my globalization settings @TiesonT. ?

Comment: I didn't test it, but it should be displayed using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Depends on whether it's happening on the server or the client (your browser). Do you have more than one browser to test with, and if so, does the same thing happen in all of them?

Comment: @TiesonT. I use Firefox, but I have tried chrome and the same thing happens. In my dump, display my number with point, when my number is rendered, its show with comma. Ex. dump (44.23), ex. rendered (44,23)

Comment: That sounds like a system setting, which means you probably want to ask that question on Super User. That being said, [settings for OSX - Yosemite](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18445?locale=en_US). For Windows, it varies somewhat with the OS version, but basically it's Control Panel > Region

Comment: Yes, In my region configuration, the decimals are shown with comma, I have changed to point, but the problem continues. I have also cleared the cache

Comment: most likely it's about the `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ....)`. [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Answer (score 0):

The twig derivate in the symfony configuration also supports the following entries:

```
number_format:
    decimals: 2
    decimal_point: '.'
```

Comment: Hi! Show my edit please, i have changed my conf, this is correct?

Comment: yes see the link [http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-default-date-and-number-format-configuration](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-default-date-and-number-format-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the way numbers are displayed either by changing the locale to one that uses "." instead or by using the number_format filter in Twig. The latter can be tedious if you need the formatting by default across the application.

**Changing locale**

config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en # Or any other locale that uses . instead of ,
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

**Using number_format in Twig template:**

```
{{ 66.45 | number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```